# Ant Incremental build numbers for zip names

Tags: ant, build-numbers

I'm doing a project at uni and would like to create zip files which name (just a build number) increments after each successful build.

What's the easiest way to do this?
Is it a case of having to write a custom task?
Or is there some built in functionality that will allow me to do this simply and easily?

I did have a look at the Zip task manual, but couldn't spot anything that might be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen the [`BuildNumber` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/buildnumber.html)?

Run that task, and then name the zip file based on the property.

Answer (score 0):

One easy alternative solution would be to  include a timestamp into your file name:

```
myapp_20090326-1522.zip for the build made on 2009-03-26 at 15:22.
```

That's what many projects do. Also avoids problems if multiple people may create builds on their machines; you don't need to coordinate build numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) CI server to build your project, you can use the Hudson build number.  Here's a quick example of getting the BUILD_NUMBER environment variable (which is injected by Hudson):

```
<property environment="env" description="System environment variables (including those set by Hudson)"/>
<!-- set the build number based on environment variable, otherwise blank -->
<condition property="buildNumber" value=".${env.BUILD_NUMBER}" else="">
    <isset property="env.BUILD_NUMBER" />
</condition>
```